# Maven not finding tests from a test suite class

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am using maven to run a series of JUnit tests, I have changed the code so that instead of using @Test annotations I use a test suite class like this:

```
public class MyTests {
  public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite ts = new TestSuite("My Test Suite");
    ts.addTest(new CustomTestCase1("Test 1"));
    ts.addTest(new CustomTestCase2("Test 2"));
    ...
    return ts;
  }
}
```

When I run a

```
mvn clean -U -fn -Dtest=MyTests test
```

I get a **no tests were executed!**

Can anybody point me to how I could run the test using maven instead of creating a test runner for each class?

Comment: Hello, why do you not use '@Test' and '@Suite' annotations ? Because I think it is not possible with Junit 4/5 but only with JUnit 3.

Comment: @fandango because I want to be able to have "CustomTestCase1" as reusable test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run a suite using the `-DrunSuite` flag:

```
mvn clean -U -fn -DrunSuite=MyTests test
```